# How to call Post method with multiple parameter from C# project

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I Have created a web api project , in values controller i created a method InsertHeading which takes three parameters and returns back a unique id. The method looks like this :-

```
  public int InsertHeading([FromBody]string appid, [FromBody]string type, [FromBody]string detail)
        {
            int x = 1;
            return 1;


        }
```

I tried this variant as well

```
[HttpPost]
      public int InsertHeading(string appid, string type, string detail)
            {
                int x = 1;
                return 1;
            }
```

This piece of code is running when i give url like :- http://server:port/LoggingAPi/Values/InsertHeading
from soap UI.

But when i try to call this method from my c# code i am getting 404 error how ever i try. Here are two ways i have tried :-

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxx:45422/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var append = new MasterLogInfo() { appid = "2", type = "request", detail = "test call from genesys" };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("LoggingAPI/Values/InsertMasterloginfo", append);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Get the URI of the created resource.
                Uri finalURL = response.Headers.Location;
            }

        }
```

Method 2:-

```
//  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53117/");
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxx:45422/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
   new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var user = new MasterLogInfo();
                user.appid = "100";
                user.typeRequest = "Test";
                user.detail = "test call from genesys";

      var response = client.PostAsync("LoggingAPI/Values/InsertMasterloginfo", new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

            //    var response = client.PostAsync("Values/InsertHeading", new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Get the URI of the created resource.
                    Uri finalURL = response.Headers.Location;
                }

            }
```

If i use FromBody tag in parameters i get 500 internal server error, without it i get 404 error. Can anybody tell me what am i missing.I have removed the body of insert Heading for security purpose

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that represents the payload coming in from the post. Then you can use it in the action parameters e.g. `public int InsertHeading([FromBody] MyObject myObject)`

Comment: what changes are required in the function calling part ? otherwise if i use above way i still get 500 internal server error

Comment: Change the endpoint from `LoggingAPI/Values/InsertMasterloginfo` to `LoggingAPI/Values/InsertHeading`

Comment: that was just for testing, i have been using insertHeading only

Comment: Are you calling the API from another web project, and if so, does the 500 come from the API you call, or the API doing the calling?

Comment: yes the api insertheading is different. It is meant to be consumed by multiple other web services. The one from where i am consuming is totally different and console application in current scenerio. 500 internal server is coming in case of calling the main web service'

Comment: What version of .NET are you using for the API?